# Need to uninstall apache2 in Ubuntu

Tags: apache2

**Command :-**

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2.2-common
```

**Result :-**

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.8) but it is not going to be installed
 apache2-mpm-prefork : Depends: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: apache2-api-20120211
                       Depends: apache2 (>= 2.4)
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork libapache2-mod-php5 apache2.2-common apache2-api-20120211`

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2*
```

Or :

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

this command will remove all packages whose name starts with apache, hope it helps

```
sudo apt-get remove "^apache.*",
```